# What is a fast way to multiply a Schubert polynomial by an elementary symmetric polynomial (specifically $x_1\cdots x_k$)?

Tags: co.combinatorics, schubert-calculus

What is a computationally fast way to get the coefficients of Schubert polynomials in the expansion of the product of a Schubert polynomial and an elementary symmetric polynomial? I know "fast" is relative because this is a #P-complete problem, but I'm sure there are faster ways than what I am doing. I know the result is governed by [Sottile's Pieri formula](https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9505001), but how to find the elements of the formula beyond brute force searching is not obvious.

I really only care about the product with polynomials of the form
$$x_1x_2\cdots x_k$$
In that case I tried using Monk's formula and the fact that
$$x_i=\mathfrak S_{s_i} - \mathfrak S_{s_{i-1}}$$
However this results in massive cancellation and hence it uses a lot of memory and is not very fast.

**Edit:** After posting this I thought of a much faster way. Some of the cancellation in multiplying by $\mathfrak S_{s_i}-\mathfrak S_{s_{i-1}}$ is predictable, so there's no need to directly use Monk's formula to multiply by $x_i$, you only need to compute the part that doesn't immediately cancel. I just tested this on a large example, the new method took $29$ seconds and the old method took $9$ minutes and $42$ seconds, so definitely a massive improvement. I am still looking for better ways though if anybody knows any.

Comment: By Sottile's formula I'm assuming you mean the Pieri rule in https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9505001? It seems like that would be a natural candidate at any rate.

Comment: @Sam Yes, that's the one I mean.

Comment: @Sam Usually positive, combinatorial formulas are not fast.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah I don't know much about the computational aspects.